# помогите совместить лейблы

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qcombobox

помогите с оптимизацией кода, получила проект от студента, которого отчислили, но проект интересный, хотела-бы его довести до ума, но не хватает определённых умений.
Нужно в в файле mainWindow совместить закомментированные строчки с кодом, который уже есть (объединить изменение лейблов), нижу прикрепляю все файлы проекта, надеюсь на помощь от добрых людей, заранее большое спасибо.

код Python файла mainWindow

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1090, 690)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1090, 690))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1090, 690))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Просмотр Плана Секции")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #
        # self.myDict = {
        #     '110': ['Комната 111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', ],
        #     '210': ['211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', ],
        #     '120': ['121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', ],
        #     '220': ['221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', ],
        #     '130': ['131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', ],
        #     '230': ['231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', ],
        #     '140': ['141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', ],
        #     '240': ['241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', ],
        #     '150': ['151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', ],
        #     '250': ['251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', ],
        #     '160': ['161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', ],
        #     '260': ['261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', ],
        #     '170': ['171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', ],
        #     '270': ['271', '272', '273', '274', '275', '276', '277', '278', ],
        #     '180': ['181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '188', ],
        #     '280': ['281', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '287', '288', ],
        #     '190': ['191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', ],
        #     '290': ['291', '292', '293', '294', '295', '296', '297', '298', ],
        # }
        #
        # self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        # self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        #
        # self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        #
        # self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        #
        #
        #
        # for c in self.myDict.keys():
        #     self.comboBox.addItem(f"секция {c}")
        # self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 143, 0,)
        #
        # row = 1
        # column = 0
        # self.labels = []
        # for i, lbl in enumerate(self.myDict['110']):
        #     label = QLabel(lbl, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        #     label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 145, 45);")
        #     label.setFixedSize(105, 21)
        #     self.labels.append(label)
        #
        #     column = i
        #     if i > 3:
        #         row = 2
        #         column = i - 4
        #     self.layout.addWidget(self.labels[i], row, column, 1, 1)
        #
        # self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.current_text_changed)

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 40, 209, 50))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")


        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 606, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 120, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")

        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 445, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")


        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 185, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")

        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 250, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")

        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 315, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")

        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(845, 380, 209, 50))
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")



        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 775, 535))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")


        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 117, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 117, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 117, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 117, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")


        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 540, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")


        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 540, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")

        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 540, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")

        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 540, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")

        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 42, 200, 40))
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    # def current_text_changed(self, text):
    #     lbl = self.myDict[text[-3:]]
    #     for i, l in enumerate(self.labels):
    #         l.setText(lbl[i])


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 110"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 210"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 120"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 220"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 130"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 230"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 140"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 240"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 150"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 250"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 160"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 260"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(12, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 170"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(13, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 270"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(14, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 180"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(15, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 280"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(16, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 190"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(17, _translate("MainWindow", "секция 290"))



        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Студенты"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комменданты"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проживание"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Секции"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Корпусы"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 131"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 132"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 133"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 134"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 135"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 136"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 137"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 138"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбор секции"))
```

код Python файла main

```
import sys
from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from getRooms import Lodgers
from Roms import Ui_Rooms


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.rоом_rect = {
            '131': 0,
            '132': 1,
            '133': 2,
            '134': 3,
            '135': 4,
            '136': 5,
            '137': 6,
            '138': 7,
        }


        self.lodgers = Lodgers()
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.openlodgers)
        self.lodgers.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow)

        self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.openrooms)

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("section_sketch.png"))
        self.lodgers._getRooms()  # формирование списка self.lodgers.rоом_beds
        self.drowRooms()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

    # Метод для отрисовки
    def drowRooms(self):
        self.Rooms = []
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 131 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя через список)
            self.scene.addRect(195, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1311
            self.scene.addRect(240, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1312
            self.scene.addRect(195, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1313
            self.scene.addRect(240, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1314
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 132 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(330, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1321
            self.scene.addRect(375, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1322
            self.scene.addRect(330, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1323
            self.scene.addRect(375, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1324
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 133 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(465, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1331
            self.scene.addRect(510, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1332
            self.scene.addRect(465, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1333
            self.scene.addRect(510, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1334
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 134 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(595, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1341
            self.scene.addRect(640, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1342
            self.scene.addRect(595, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1343
            self.scene.addRect(640, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1344
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 135 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(595, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1351
            self.scene.addRect(640, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1352
            self.scene.addRect(595, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1353
            self.scene.addRect(640, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1354
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 136 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(465, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1361
            self.scene.addRect(510, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1362
            self.scene.addRect(465, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1363
            self.scene.addRect(510, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1364
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 137 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(330, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1371
            self.scene.addRect(375, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1372
            self.scene.addRect(330, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1373
            self.scene.addRect(375, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1374
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 138 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(195, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1381
            self.scene.addRect(240, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1382
            self.scene.addRect(195, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1383
            self.scene.addRect(240, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1384

        # список сформированный в новом классе
        for k, v in self.lodgers.rоом_beds:
            self.Rooms[self.rоом_rect[k]][int(v)].setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(Qt.red))

    def openrooms(self):
        self.hide()
        self.rooms.show()

    def openlodgers(self):
        self.hide()
        self.lodgers.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна проживающие) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow(self):
        self.lodgers._getRooms()
        self.drowRooms()  # отрисовка
        self.lodgers._getRooms()  # формирование списка
        self.lodgers.close()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

код Python файла getRooms

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from lodgers import Ui_lodgers


class Lodgers(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_lodgers):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Lodgers, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza.db')
        sdb.open()
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        self.model.setTable("users")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.select()

        self.tableView_1.setModel(self.model)

        self.rоом_beds = []


        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.on_add_record)  # Добавить запись
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.on_del_record)  # Удалить запись

    def on_add_record(self):
        row = self.tableView_1.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()
        if self.tableView_1.selectionModel().currentIndex().row() == -1:
            row = 0
            self.model.insertRow(row)
        else:
            row = row + 1
            self.model.insertRow(row)

        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 0), 'ФИО NEW')
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 1), '0000')
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 2), '0')
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 3), '0')
        self.model.submit()

    def on_del_record(self):
        self.model.removeRow(self.tableView_1.currentIndex().row())
        self.model.select()



    def _getRooms(self):
        self.rоом_beds = []
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            if self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 2)) == 1:
                rоом_bed = str(self.model.data(
                    self.model.index(row, 1)))[:3], \
                           str(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 1)))[3]
                self.rоом_beds.append(rоом_bed)
```